# WinRT - How get track name from audio streaming?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

How I can get audio track property from audio stream?
for example for this audio stream? http://radio.bestfm.fm:8080/bestfm_mp3

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I'm not really too much of an expert in this area, but you should be looking at how to read in ID3 tags.  Above and beyond that, you'll need to show a code example of what you have so far, so people can see where you're getting stuck.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know where to start :)
I read about ICY-MetaData, but it gave no success.
I download this sample - https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=eb0868f2135b874c&id=EB0868F2135B874C!1037&authkey=!AGSYfCVvCasGArI , but when I replace uri to my stream nothing happens

Comment: What do you mean by Audio Property here?